# Age in seconds calculator

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I want to  make a calculator that calculates someones age in seconds and all the programs that do that only get the days. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Well perhaps it is a good starting point to add the code that calculates the number of days...

Comment: No Frank, sorry, I mean, this isn't a coding factory, you have to learn how to ask in this site. I little advice, go to how to ask, another, add attempt to work here, if you don't, the users will downvote, and eventually the question will be close

Comment: Calculate the number of days. Days * 24 gives the number of hours. days * 24 * 60 gives minutes. Days * 24 * 60 * 60 gives the number of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like an algorithm problem. What you would want though is to just keep breaking years into smaller units so for example.

1 year = 365.25 days -> 1 day = 24 hours -> 1 hour = 60 minutes -> 1 minute = 60 seconds

This should be relatively easy to implement in code.